# Stop execution of a function if a certain condition is met by the nedb findone

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, discord.js, nedb

I have placed the following code in my function but when a certain condition is met it doesnt stop executing the function how do i fix this?

thanks for ur time

```
db.findOne({nickname: args[2]}, (err,data) => {
        if(data.nickname === args[2])
          return;
      });
```

Comment: What function are you trying to stop?

Comment: The findOne callback is ran asynchronously. I guess you sould read how asynchronous JavaScript works, as a syncrhonous function cannot know the findOne result before ending. Just head Google and search "asyncrhonous JavaScript tutorial". Will help you a lot as JavaScript is mainly asynchronous event-diven. Also, as @Taplar says, your question is vague. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask